# Finetune a Caffe model in Torch

Tags: machine-learning, lua, caffe, conv-neural-network, torch

I want to finetune a neural net that has been pretrained. However, this model was made in Caffe and I would like to work in Torch.
I have tried `loadcaffe`, but this does not seem focused on finetuning.
Is there another tool that makes this possible? Or can the Caffe model be converted to a Torch net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is

1. use [loadcaffe](https://github.com/szagoruyko/loadcaffe) to convert your Caffe pretrained network into a Torch version.
   (right after you can save it on disk with `torch.save("net.t7", model)`)
2. write Torch code to fine-tune it.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!